# Extended DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

How can I add this **(ExtendedDataGrid)** to my Silverlight project ?

Here is the link to the project I am referring to

http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com

Error is:

> You can't add a reference to ExtendedGrid.dll as it was not built
>   against the Silvelright runtime. Silverlight projects will only work
>   with Silverlight assemblies.

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

That project was built for `WPF` and not `Silverlight`.

> This is extended version of **WPF toolkit DataGrid** control.
>   Please note: As code of wpf datatgrid in wpftoolkit is moved inside
>   ExtendedDataGrid project , kindly update Microsoft.Windows.Controls
>   namespace  to ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls to use existing
>   objects.

The error message you included in your post states as much.

> Silvelright projects will only work with Silvelright assemblies

Remember Silverlight is a stripped down version of .Net used for the browser plugin, and as such will not work with full version of .Net.

Unless you actually go into the source code of that project and try to port it to silverlight then there is currently no other way for you to add that project to your Silverlight project.

I would advise looking into the Silvelright toolkit and it's datagrid. It may not be as full featured as the one you are trying to reference but it covers the basic requirements for a datagrid in silverlight. There are also some open sourced versions that have been extended for silvelright.